# Valor de variável diferente em sub-select

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SET @VAR = 'N';
SELECT 'TESTE1','OI',@VAR := 'S' AS T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TESTE2','OI',@VAR AS T 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *  FROM (  SELECT 'TESTE3','OI',@VAR AS T ) AS TAB 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TESTE4','OI',@VAR AS T
```

Alguém pode me explicar o por quê de o valor de "TESTE3" ser "N" e para os demais, "S"? E também, como contornar o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O motivo é simples, independente da ordem em você dispõe os select, o que esta dentro do parentese será executado primeiro, logo, não terá sofrido a alteração feita externamente. Neste caso banco de dados trabalha de maneira semelhante a nos na matemática executando o que esta dentro do parentese primeiro. Lembrando que isso acontece devido a plano de execução calculado pelo banco decidindo executar a consulta nesta ordem.

Você pode testar isso fazendo o seguinte select:

```
SET @VAR = 'Z';
SELECT 'TESTE1','OI',@VAR AS T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TESTE2','OI',@VAR AS T 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *  FROM (  SELECT 'TESTE3','OI',@VAR := 'N' AS T ) AS TAB 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TESTE4','OI',@VAR AS T
```

Que retornara:

```
TESTE1  OI  N
TESTE2  OI  N
TESTE3  OI  N
TESTE4  OI  N
```

Ele te ajudará a notar que a alteração realizada dentro do parentese foi executada primeiro, por isso os demais registro sofrem a mesma alteração da variável.

Dito isso a maneira de contornar o problema, é entendendo este conceito e passando as alterações para o escopro interno, igual eu fiz no exemplo para te mostrar a solução, isso deve bastar para corrigir o problema.

Comment: Boa, Luiz! Mas tem alguma sugestão para contornar o problema?

Comment: Neste caso você deve colocar a alteração dentro de um subselect se possível. Deve sempre pensar no que quer que execute primeiro

Comment: @CleberGriff somei a solução de contorno a resposta da questão para deixa-la melhor explicada, atendendo sua duvida.

Comment: Perfeito! Devo esperar mais 21 horas para conceder a recompensa, mas já é sua. Obrigado!

Comment: shoooooooooooow